# "Do until" loop exits the macro before the "for each" loop ends

Tags: excel, vba

For each row of my worksheet, I'm trying to browse cells. I'll stop when I encounter an empty cell. Then I want to go to the following row.

In order to do this I'm using a "Do until" loop with a "IsEmpty" condition. This "Do until" loop is inside a "For each" loop. The "For each" loop is used to go from one range to another in the first column. From A1 to A2, to A3 etc.

I manage to browse the first line successfully. But I can't manage to get down to the second row, and the following ones. I'm assuming that the "Do until" loop exits the macro without letting Excel read the "Next rng" statement...

My macro exits, and the active cell is the first empty cell of the first row. (we should now go to the second row, not stop)

Here is my code :

```
Sub label_clusters()

Dim rng As Range, iCounter As Integer
iCounter = 1

For Each rng In Feuil1.Range("A1:A24")

If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
Sheets("Feuil2").Cells(iCounter, 1) = rng.Value
Sheets("Feuil2").Cells(iCounter, 2) = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
iCounter = iCounter + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
End If

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = True

If ActiveCell.Column <> 1 Then
Sheets("Feuil2").Cells(iCounter, 1) = rng.Value
Sheets("Feuil2").Cells(iCounter, 2) = ActiveCell.Value
iCounter = iCounter + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
End If

Loop

Next rng

End Sub
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but after googling again and againd I'm now short on ideas. Any suugestion will do =) Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
```

After you finish the first row, `ActiveCell` is the first empty cell, and `ActiveCell.Column` is > 1.  So for each iteration of the `for each` loop after the first, the first code block gets skipped, and the `ActiveCell` never gets updated to the first cell of the next row.

looking at your code, both `if` statements seem to be superfluous.  I think the code will perform correctly if you delete both `if` and `end if` lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew, with your answer it took me less than one minute to figure this out.
I see my mistake clearly now. Droping the if didn't do it. But, having understood the problem. I added "rng.Select" at the top. So that after I finish one row I start by uptading my active cell.